# how to replace slashes "/" in in mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `varchar` type column in a database where i am inserting a date in this format `Y-MM-DD` but now I am trying to change datatype of the column to `timestamp` but the problem is I have some data in `Y/MM/DD` this format from `id 941` to so on. how can i remove slashes `/` to hyphens `-` so i can only be able to change datatype to timestamp

```
update tablename set created_at = substring_index(created_at,'-',2)
```

This query is completely wrong but know only this/

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, you want to update all the values of the field `created_at`, and replace the "/" with "-".
To achieve this, you can use this :

```
UPDATE tablename SET created_at = REPLACE(created_at, "/", "-");
```

You can check the following link for more information about the function `REPLACE()` in MySQL: [MySQL REPLACE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp).

Hope this helps!

Comment: exactly this is I want don't know why I got negative votes

Comment: Sure. You can ask here if it is related to this question, or create a new post if it is about a different problem.

Comment: again a question maybe if you can help now my formate is dd-mm/YYYY how can i reverse the order in YYYY-m-d

Comment: You can use the Reverse() function in MySQL. UPDATE tablename SET created_at = REVERSE(created_at); The following link will inform you more about this function: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_reverse.asp. Please mark the answer as correct if your problem was solved.